# Emacs' org-batch-agenda exports wrong report

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I want to print my todo list to shell with the following command:

```
emacs -batch -l ~/.emacs -eval '(org-batch-agenda-csv "t")'
```

The problem is that this command prints the agenda (like when using the "a" key) instead of the todo list. I haven't rebound any of this keys, so I don't know why this happens here.

Has anybody an idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this using `Org-mode version 7.8.03 (release_7.8.03.321.gaac1c)` and it worked as expected (for both `org-batch-agenda-csv "t"` and `org-batch-agenda-csv "a"`).  What version are you using?

Comment: I was using a 6.xx but updated and now it works as expected too. Thank you.